# retrieving collection in magento-2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-5.4

I want use below query in my custom module

```
SELECT category_name
FROM faq_category
WHERE id = ANY (SELECT category_name FROM faq_category_description WHERE category_name = 1);
```

But i don't know syntax of query in magento2 ?If anyone knows please explain me....

Comment: have you a colleciton for your table?

Comment: yes. i have it .

Comment: Ok you query is not correct i think you can do it with a joint can you print a sturcture of you two tables and what tou want exactly?

Answer (score 5):

I hope this might help you

```
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection'); 
$orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['si' => 'sales_order_item'], "main_table.entity_id = si.order_id"); 

$orderCollection->getSelect()
                ->join(
                    'sales_order_item',
                    'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id',
                    array(
                        'name'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                        'qty'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ",")')
                    )
                );

$orderCollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
   if(($order->getQty() * 1) == 10){
        $productName[] = $order->getName();
   }
}
```

Comment: array(
                        'name'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                        'qty'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ",")')
                    )

Comment: which means ....how to apply in my table

Comment: you will get Ordered Product Names which has 10 QTY

Comment: Is it like WHERE condition?

Comment: please see my updated Query

Comment: can you change this query also in magento ORM

select parent_id, group_concat(concat(firstname,street,city,address_type)) from sales_order_address GROUP BY parent_id


i have $select = $result->getSelect(); 

Now next change into magento 2